# Is hyperledger sawtooth under apache or intel corporation?

Tags: apache, blockchain, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

Hyperledger sawtooth is maintained by Apache or Inter corporation?

[image]

At the footer there is intel corporation, if we want to move the project to production which is built on Hyperledger sawtooth, do we need to pay to intel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Hyperledger Sawtooth](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core/blob/master/LICENSE) is open source software, and is free to download and use.

The project was initially created by Intel, as blockchain software using Intel SGX CPU instructions to implement PoET (Proof of Elapsed Time) consensus. Intel then donated it to the **[Hyperledger Foundation](https://hyperledger.org/)** as open source software, under the [Apache 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) open source license. Developers from Intel and many other companies and individuals are members of the Hyperledger community and contribute to the Sawtooth project.

The Hyperledger Foundation is a global collaborative organisation 'created to advance cross-industry blockchain technologies' which incubates and supports several open source blockchain projects. It was [launched in 2016](https://www.hyperledger.org/announcements/2016/02/09/linux-foundations-hyperledger-project-announces-30-founding-members-and-code-proposals-to-advance-blockchain-technology) as part of the Linux Foundation, similar to the CNCF and Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to pay Intel. Intel donated Hyperledger Sawtooth to The Linux Foundation, which manages it under the Hyperledger consortium.

Hyperledger Sawtooth is licensed with Apache 2, but your application's source code can use Sawtooth and be open (or even closed) source under another license. You just use the Sawtooth APIs/SDKs/CLIs.